# CreationTime retuning more dates then expected

Tags: powershell

I wrote this script to show me all the SQL BAK jobs which backed up on the previous night. However I am getting not only last nights backups but the previous nights as well.

```
$bak_path = "\\nas2\sqlbackups"

get-childitem -path $bak_path -Filter "*.bak" 
    -Exclude *master*.**,*model*.**,*msdb*.** -File -recurse  | 
    sort-object -Property CreationTime | select-object -last 200
```

Would someone take a look at this and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well it doesn't look like you're filtering on a date. Which bit of that are you expecting to only give you last nights files?

Comment: Interesting, I am still getting last nights data. However I get the previous nights as well. I thought that the CreationTime would only provide me last nights data.  What do I need to change in my script to provide me only last nights data?

Comment: At the moment you're just getting the last 200 files ordered by when they were created. You'd need to pipe to `Where-Object` and provide a DateTime value for the `CreationTime` that's after 00:00 of yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only sorting by the creationtime, you are not filtering by it.

The following will give you all files created on the day before and onward:

```
$yesterday = (Get-Date -hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddDays(-1)
get-childitem -path $bak_path -Filter "*.bak" 
-Exclude *master*.**,*model*.**,*msdb*.** -File -recurse | where {$_.CreationTime -gt $yesterday)
```

If you need all files for example starting from 1pm the day before just set `-hour` to 13 and you are good to go.

Comment: Yes that worked! I see all the SQL BAK files from the previous night. The exact number of SQL BAK files that I was expecting to see.  I noticed that one file came back with the date modified of  "1/1/1980" however when I checked the header information of the SQL BAK file it did back up last night "2015-01-29 17:45:07.000".  All the other files show the following date range between  "1/29/2015 6:00PM" and "1/29/2015 7:30PM"only one file has the date modified of  "1/1/1980 7:00PM" ,did I miss something here, very strange?

Comment: @user36578 1/1/1980 sounds like a reference date to me. Why you get it in date modified though I can't explain. If my answer solved your problem please remember to accept it.